# Angular UI-GRID does not display anything when JSON string is return from $http.get or $http.post

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

When I submit a JSON array through post and return the same as a string and assign to `UI-GRID.data` it does not display anything.

Even when I return JSON string through `$http.get` and assign it to `UI-GRID.data` it does not display anything.

```
var httpGetRequest = $http.get('http://localhost/service1/WcfJsonRestService.Service1.svc/data/11',"");

httpGetRequest.success(function(data) {
    $scope.getResp = data;
    alert("****Received Data in success **** " + JSON.parse(data));       
    $scope.gridOptions.data = data;

});
```

The return data is same as I sent, no difference. I am stuck there.

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse(data.data)`?

Comment: Yes I have tried $scope.gridOptions.data = JSON.parse(data); Does not work

Comment: please try logging out `data.data`. It's a property on that response. You should have it set up like `function(response)` and then examine `response.data`

Comment: httpGetRequest.success(function(response) {
                       $scope.getResp = JSON.parse(response.data);
                       alert("****Received Data in success **** " + $scope.getResp);       
                       $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.getResp;
                       
                     });

Comment: did I use the write syntax above, it does not work

Comment: Just try `console.log(response.data);` and see if this is the data you want

Comment: Yes the data is exactly the same...JSON formatted string, it displays in the alert too

Comment: Check what your service is returning then

Comment: this is the string I return:[{"USER_NAME":"COR","FULL_NAME":"Pet","ROLE":"TE","IS_ACTIVE":"Y"},{"USER_NAME":"COR","FULL_NAME":"Gru","ROLE":"TE","IS_ACTIVE":"Y"},{"USER_NAME":"COR","FULL_NAME":"McC","ROLE":"TE","IS_ACTIVE":"Y"},{"USER_NAME":"COR","FULL_NAME":"Sam","ROLE":"PM","IS_ACTIVE":"Y"},{"USER_NAME":"COR","FULL_NAME":"Cha","ROLE":"PM","IS_ACTIVE":"Y"}]  from the service in console.log()

Comment: Any help will be highly appreciated? I am stuck and cannot move forward

Comment: Where is your `$http.post` call?

Comment: $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/Service1/WcfJsonRestService.Service1.svc/PostData',
                data: $scope.gridOptions.data,
                headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'plain/text'
                   }}).then(function(result,status, headers, config) {
                             $scope.gridOptions.data = JSON.parse(result.data);
                      }, function(error) {
                           $scope.postResp = error;
                           alert("Received Data in error " + error.data);  
           });

Comment: My post response I have the same problem, I am posting data from the grid and then return the same data from my webservice as a JSON string- the grid shows data initially, but it does not show the data after the response

Comment: Take a look at my response to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950466/how-do-i-get-data-to-show-up-in-angular-ui-grid-from-an-http-request.  It might help you with your data display issues.