# How do I get data to show up in angular ui.grid from an $http request continuation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers

Okay I'm going to keep this as short as possible.

I've been studying Angular for a bit now and there's still a lot I need to learn, right now I'm trying to figure out how to connect end to end with headers in a service which is completely new to me as I've never done end to end integration.

The code below is provided from another stack overflow answer and what I want to know is how do I connect what they have with say dataService.js. This is all new to me so I'm trying to ask this the best way possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="gridController">
        <!-- Initialise the grid with ng-init call -->
        <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ng-init="GetGridData(urlList)">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="Scripts/ng/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ng-grid/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Scripts/ng-grid/ui-rid.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid']);

        app.controller("gridController",
            ["$scope", "$attrs", "$element", "$compile", "$http", "$q",
            function ($scope, $attrs, $element, $compile, $http, $q)
            {
                $scope.urlList = "YourSourceUrl";

                function fnGetList(url)
                {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $http.get(url)
                        .success(function (data)
                        {
                            deferred.resolve(data);
                        })
                        .error(function (errorMessage)
                        {
                            alert(errorMessage);
                            deferred.reject;
                        });
                    return deferred.promise;
                };

                $scope.GetGridData = function (url)
                {
                    console.log("In GetGridData: " + "Getting the data");

                    //  Test Only - un-comment if you need to test the grid statically.

                    //$scope.loadData = ([
                    //        {
                    //            "UserName": "Joe.Doe",
                    //            "Email": "Joe.Doe@myWeb.com"
                    //        },
                    //        {
                    //            "UserName": "Jane.Doe",
                    //            "Email": "Jane.Doe@myWeb.com"
                    //        },
                    //]);
                    //return;

                    fnGetList(url).then(function (content)
                    {
                        //  Assuming your content.data contains a well-formed JSON

                        if (content.data !== undefined)
                        {
                            $scope.loadData = JSON.parse(content.data);
                        }
                    });
                };

                $scope.gridOptions =
                {
                    data: 'loadData',
                    columnDef:
                        [
                            { field: 'UserName', name: 'User' },
                            { field: 'Email', name: 'e-mail' }
                        ]
                };

            }
        ]);
</script>

</body>
```

Provided from: [How do I get data to show up in angular ui.grid from an $http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950466/how-do-i-get-data-to-show-up-in-angular-ui-grid-from-an-http-request/28015160#28015160?newreg=1f8867130e614edf8794f7dd3f4d5209)

Comment: $scope.urlList = "YourSourceUrl"; <== Do you have a URL you are using, is it setup correctly and can you seen it returning data via Postman or another tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I use is to pass the URL as an AJAX call and then wait for the data to get back after which I connect the JSON data to the ng-grid. Note that there will be a delay in getting the data back from the URL and you will have to have a timer that will keep checking for the data return begin valid.

```
function setCar(){
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: '/Test/ConfigConnect.json?details=&car='+car+'&id=1',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
        configData = data;
    }
});}
```

The timer function that is part of the javascirpt is also given below.

```
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      $scope.$apply(updatePage);
}, 500);

var updatePage = function() {    
    if (typeof configData !== 'undefined')
    {
        clearInterval(timer);
        $scope.loadData = configData;
    }
};
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, sorry for not responding :)